# Best way to Check if records exists in Core Data DB

Tags: ios, core-data

I am working on an iOS app and I want to loop through data to check to see if the records exists in the Core Data DB.

I have about 100 records that I want to loop through and see if the record exists.

Should I use NSPredicate to make a fetch request on every loop, or should I make the fetch request once for all the items in the DB and put them in an Array and do the check on an array?
I guess my real question is what is expensive on the device to do?

thank you

Comment: Some general advice: Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make one request to fetch all your records and then loop through the returned array using fast iteration.

> I guess my real question is what is expensive on the device to do?

The answer to this question is actually to let CoreData do the management for you. It will load the objects as "faults" which do not take up much memory and only load them from the DB when you access them.

With 100 records, you will not hit limits either way (performance or memory) assuming your objects are of a reasonable size. If you objects are very large (say images) CoreData might not be the best way to store them.

Comment: Can I use NSpredicate to search the returned array from CoreData?